# Cartesian Product in Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-algebra, cartesian-product

I'm a total begginer in Relational Algebra  and I don't manage to fully understand how cartesian product works.

I want to know what happen in cartesian product when my two table have common attributes. I have no problem to understand when both table don't have any attribute in common.

For instance I tried to understand on example I made myself.

```
T1                          T2
----------                  -----------
A   B   C                   A    B   D
1   4   7                   1    4   8
2   5   3                   2    9   5
4   7   1                   7    3   2
```

If I want to do T1 x T2, when I want to write the line that is the concatenation of the first line of T1  `A=1 , B=4 , C=7` and the second line of T2 `A=2 ,B=9 ,C=5` , what happen to the column A and B ?

If you could show me the result of T1 x T2 it would be really useful!

Comment: Please give a reference to your relational algebra variant. Many algebras have relations with ordered attributes, which can have duplicate names; so they can calculate a product of any two relations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian products of tables that contains same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942237/cartesian-products-of-tables-that-contains-same-columns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: As discussed on comment section. I'm editing this answer for a proper understanding of the question.

As this is a possible duplicate, refer to this link:
[Cartesian products of tables that contains same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942237/cartesian-products-of-tables-that-contains-same-columns)

First, it depends on the algebra that you are using. For some, the cartesian product can be done between tables with common attributes, similar to a cross join, and on other algebras the cartesian product is not permitted, so you would have to rename the attributes.

p.s: Look up Cross Joins as they are similar to a cartesian product but with no conditions to join, see expected result of a cross join of your example tables:

```
    T1                      T2                T1 X T2
----------              -----------     =    ----------------------------
A   B   C                A    B   D          T1.A T1.B T1.C T2.A T2.B T2.D
1   4   7                1    4   8           1     4   7    1    4    8
2   5   3                2    9   5           1     4   7    2    9    5
4   7   1                7    3   2           1     4   7    7    3    2
                                              2     5   3    1    4    8
                                              2     5   3    2    9    5
                                              2     5   3    7    3    2
                                              4     7   1    1    4    8
                                              4     7   1    2    9    5
                                              4     7   1    7    3    2
```

refer link: [What is the difference between Cartesian product and cross join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861417/what-is-the-difference-between-cartesian-product-and-cross-join)

Also, i highly recommend you to check this out and try it yourself!

RelaX - relational algebra calculator
http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/index.htm

Comment: When i try my example in the calculator you gave me I get `join would result in non unique column names; the following columns appear in both relations: A, B`. So Should I conclude that I can't make a cartesian product without renaming A and B ?

Comment: Oh snap! I misunderstood your question. I'll edit my answer. But to correct it here already. Cartesian product is a case of natural join where the joined relations don't have any attribute names in common. What i misunderstood for a Cross Join, which then would give you some valid result.
And, yes, you should conclude that.

Comment: Errr I think the fault is mine I dindn"t know there were a difference beetweens Cross Product and Cartesian Product! But what i meant was cross product and that's what i used on the calculator (Named cross join on the website) ! And it gave me the error message i wrote before.

Comment: Strange. I used the same data you provided as example here and it gave a valid result:

[Printscreen 1](https://puu.sh/xEnGB/f1dffda181.png)

[Printscreen 2](https://puu.sh/xEnGW/0d4997d479.png)

Comment: @Peni & VictorMedeiros Depends on the algebra variant. See my comments on the question.

Comment: @philipxy Yes! On my answer i refer to the same link. I'm kinda new here so i didn't remember to mark as possible duplicate.

Comment: @Peni & VictorMedeiros Ha ha missed a link to my own answer. Notice that that link explains that this answer is only correct for *certain algebras*, and for others wrong, hence is misleading, and the question doesn't give an algebra, so I wish the asker good luck. I find "more technical" odd--it's just more comprehensive since the question (like this one) is general. The need for a lot of cases & notions is because so many "algebras" are ridiculously complicated ([and sometimes not "algebras" at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321855/3404097)). Generally motivated by SQL apologetics.

Comment: You are completely correct, i'll edit it  so it's not so confusing.